# UIImagePickerController shows all photos even if I choose "Select Photos.." option Swift

Tags: ios, swift, permissions, uiimagepickercontroller, imagepicker

In iOS 14 beta, When I try to access the photos library, it asks for permission the first time, I select "Select Photos.." and select a few photos to show the next time I try to access photos, it shows me all the photos. ideally, it should show me the photos I selected for my app.

Code:-

```
PHPhotoLibrary.shared().presentLimitedLibraryPicker(from: currentVC) { identifiers in
                for newlySelectedAssetIdentifier in identifiers {
      }
}
```

This method shows the selection only and gives the option to add or remove photos from the selection, but how to show only selected images in the picker to use any image.